# Log in with Google with Cognito Identity Pools on Android

Tags: android, amazon-cognito, google-signin, aws-amplify

I am trying to implement sign in to google for my android App.

I currently implemented login with facebook through AWSMobileClient.getInstance().federatedSignIn(...). I am not using a hosted UI.

I get a token from google by requesting

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireActivity(), gso);

    googleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    });
```

One google successfully authenticates, I call the following method:

```
private void federatedGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    // Need to create federated sign in from aws amplify
    Log.d(TAG, "federateGoogle: " + account.getIdToken());
    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().federatedSignIn(IdentityProvider.GOOGLE.toString(), account.getIdToken(), new Callback<UserStateDetails>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final UserStateDetails userStateDetails) {
            Log.d(TAG, "AWS Federated GOOGLE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "sign-in error GOOGLE", e);
        }
    });
}
```

I get the following error:

`Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 98936aed-df1b-4849-bc03-9eb5edc364e8)`

I have triple checked my Cognito identity pool Authentication providers, Google+: Google Client ID, and it matches the one provided by the Google API console.

Is there anything I am missing, perhaps in Cognito user pools? All of the tutorials I can find are for hosted UI, is federatedSignIn() not available for google sign in?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you find any solution for that? I am facing same issue so

Comment: No, I searched for a solution, however, I found some reports that the google auth provider was broken since google+ became deprecated. Instead, I ended up implementing login with phone number using Cognito user pools

Comment: Ok, Thanks for update @Zates